# How much video content is pre buffered when using AV player with HTTP Live Streaming and can that value be changed

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am writing a video app that plays streaming videos from the web and I am using AV player to do so. My question is how do I find out how much video content is pre buffered, in MPMoviePlayerController you can see the amount of buffered content on the UISlider. I would like to show the same using AV Player and also be able to change the amount of pre buffered content.

My ideal situation is - User streaming a movie file using my app, if he pauses the play button, the movie keeps buffering just like when you watch youtube videos.

Please Help !!

Thank you.

Comment: anyone has a clue , really stuck on this part ?

Comment: Did you get any resolution to this issue ?

Answer (score 7):

You can see the amount of data that has been loaded and buffered ahead of the playhead by looking at the `AVPlayerItem loadedTimeRanges` property.

e.g.

```
AVPlayer *player;
NSArray *loadedTimeRanges = player.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges;
NSLog(@"LoadedTimeRanges: %@", loadedTimeRanges);
```

In the case of my app I can see:

```
LoadedTimeRanges: (
    "CMTimeRange: {{338070700809/1000000000 = 338.071}, {54651145016/1000000000 = 54.651, rounded}}"
)
```

where the second value (`54.651`) appears to be the amount of buffering that exists in front of the playhead.  In the case of a stall this value decreases as playback continues until reaching approximately 0.

Between 55 and 60 seconds of pre-buffered content is all I've seen – you can only examine this value and cannot force the player to buffer any more data.  You could, however, use this value to visually indicate the amount of data buffered to the user.

Comment: do you know that if playing a segment of video then going back to play it again rebuffers or all the data that got buffered stays in memory?